# Grails Execute Task on Demand

Tags: grails

Ruby on rails have rake task to execute on demand. does Grails have something similar? I know there's bootstrap but only execute when program loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did yo try custom scripts ? Its documented under http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingCustomScripts